# terraform combine data template file and each.key in a for_each block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

Using a module to create multiple IAM roles with a for_each block I am trying to pass into the policy a rendered data output and the key from the for_each loop. The name of this policy will be slightly different for each role

```
module "sso_roles" {
  source   = "git::ssh://git@gitlab.com/iam/role?ref=1.1.0"
  for_each = local.roles

  policy                 = "${data.template_file}.${each.key}_policy".rendered
  role_name              = each.key
  assume_role_policy_def = data.template_file.testing_role.rendered
  
  
}
```

These are the locals its looping through:

```
locals {
  roles = {
    "test_Read_Only" = ["arn:aws:iam::*:role/testReadOnly", "]
    "test_OS_Only" = ["arn:aws:iam::*:role/testSigninOSOnly"]
  }
}
```

what I need terraform to see when its running are these two:

```
${data.template_file.test_Read_Only_policy.rendered}
${data.template_file.test_OS_Only_policy.rendered}
```

But there is something not right with the syntax I have. The error I get says `"The "data" object must be followed by two attribute names: the data source type and the resource name."`

I don't know how to combine the `each.key` into the rendered data template file

Comment: I don't think that can work. IT would be better to create one data source and use the same variable with for_each for that data source than try to create these concatenations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would suggest is:

1. To use the data source with `for_each` and use the same variable
2. To switch to the `templatefile` built-in function and pass the value as a variable.

To achieve the first, you would do something like:

```
module "sso_roles" {
  source   = "git::ssh://git@gitlab.com/iam/role?ref=1.1.0"
  for_each = local.roles

  policy                 = data.template_file.policy[each.key].rendered
  role_name              = each.key
  assume_role_policy_def = data.template_file.testing_role.rendered
  
}

data "template_file" "policy" {
  for_each = local.roles
  ...
}
```

The second one is probably a bit more convenient and it's using a newer and better `templatefile` function [1]:

```
module "sso_roles" {
  source   = "git::ssh://git@gitlab.com/iam/role?ref=1.1.0"
  for_each = local.roles

  policy                 = templatefile("${path.module}/path/to/template/file.tpl", {
    iam_role = each.value
  })
  role_name              = each.key
  assume_role_policy_def = data.template_file.testing_role.rendered
  
  
}
```

With more information about the template file you are using I would be able to adjust the second example.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile